# Insert into a Specific Row SQL

Tags: php, sql

How do I insert into a Specific row Using the users Username so if my Username is admin it will add the information into Column "picture" and in the correct user.
It needs to be different for each user so it must know their username from the session and Update it like that Im doing it in HTML/PHP so I dont know how to Make sure it gets to the right row.

Comment: use the sql update statement

Comment: Rather than insert into a row, you want to `UPDATE` it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Update_(SQL)  Recommend getting yourself a good book on basic SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Use *Prepared Statements* in an `update` statement

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("update your_table
                       set picture = ?
                       where username = ?");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $picture);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $username);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean -

```
UPDATE MyTable SET picture = xx.jpeg WHERE username = "admin"
```